# How to Tab-complete directories when in symlinked directory?

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, auto-completion

I have a symlink:

```
/path/to/foo -> /path/to/bar/foo
```

When in `/path/to/foo` I might want to cd to `/path/to/bar/foo`:

`$ cd ../` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Then **nothing autocompletes**. I can still `cd` just fine by typing in the directory "bar", though.

Why is that? Is there a setting or trick I can apply to have that tab-complete too?

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in bash-completion (a third-party project, not affiliated with bash itself). `/etc/bash_completion` is sourced in `~/.bashrc` by default in Ubuntu, and amongst the thousands of lines of code (most of which you likely never need), is a completion function for the `cd` builtin that doesn't handle symlinked directories properly. If you disable its completion for the `cd` builtin, your tab-completion for `cd` should work more like you expect.

```
complete -r cd
```

Comment: thanks. yet do you have a link to the bug report ? this to gain further insight on this

Answer (score 1):

I think this is by design and how Bash handles the present working directory.

Compare the outputs of:

1. `pwd`
2. `pwd -P`

(The latter displays the *physical* current working directory instead of the symlinked one. [Pwd manual.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pwd.1.html))

You can make Bash to always use the physical working directory by using:

```
set -P
```

The [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/bash.1.html) states:

> **-P**      If  set,  the  shell does not follow symbolic links when executing commands such as cd that  change  the  current working 
>   directory. It  uses  the  physical  directory structure instead. By
>   default, bash follows the logical chain  of  directories  when 
>   performing  commands which change the current directory.

As a side effect, when you `cd /path/to/foo`, your `pwd` will be: `/path/to/bar/foo`.